# Checking if an attribute value contains a string within it

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
var x = document.getElementById("donor_fieldset_id");
if (x != null) {
    var child = x.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        if ($j("child[i][id*='" + phiPrefix + "']").length > 0) {
            alert("on load form donorEventHandler()");
            alert("donoorEvent" + document.getElementById("data_entry_completedId"));
            $j('#data_entry_completedId').die();
            $j('#data_entry_completedId').hide();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here the value of `phiPrefix` is already set as ENCRYPT

I want to check whether each child element has `ENCRYPT` as a part of string with it's id.
The above check is not getting successful.

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure?

Comment: `$("child[i]")` won't use the value of the variable `child[i]`. Variables aren't expanded inside strings.

Answer (score 2):

Your test should be:

```
if (child[i].id && child[i].id.indexOf(phiPrefix) != -1)
```

Putting a variable inside a jQuery selector string won't be replaced with the element.

Comment: if i try to access `child[i].id` and suppose if the element does not contain the `id`attribute will i get a null value or an empty list.?
what would be the check for it.

Comment: You'll get a null value. I've updated the answer to test for this.

Comment: shouldn't it be `child[i].id !=null && child[i].id.indexOf(phiPrefix) != -1`

Comment: `id` will either be `null` or a non-empty string. A non-empty string is always truthy. So they should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can do this with a single jQuery `each` loop:

```
var elem = $("#donor_fieldset_id");
if (elem) {
    elem.children().each(function() {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
         if (id.indexOf(phiPrefix) > -1) {
            alert("on load form donorEventHandler()");
            alert("donoorEvent"+document.getElementById("data_entry_completedId"));
         }
    });
}
```